# QueryBuilder in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, query-builder

I want to select all rows from table where filed not empty. I try do this:

```
 $qb = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select('p')
        ->from('\Vputi\UserBundle\Entity\Profile', 'p')
        ->where('p.driverLicence != :literal')
       ->setParameter('literal', null);

 var_dump($qb->getQuery()->getResult());die;
```

But getting only empty array. Where is my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change line:

```
->where('p.driverLicence != :literal')
```

to:

```
->where('p.driverLicence is not NULL')
```